# Score for Solr documents changes when field is set to "stored=false"

Tags: solr

I am confused because the scores that Solr computes change when I do not store a specific field anymore.

In my schema.xml I use dynamic fields in the following way (Solr version is 7.5):

```
<dynamicField name="*_fct_c" type="text_default" omitNorms="false"/>
```

The type "text_default" is defined as:

```
<fieldType name="text_default" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" omitNorms="true">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="[\p{Punct}&amp;&amp;[^\-_]]" replacement=" "/>
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory"
                    generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0"
                    catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"
                    splitOnNumerics="0" preserveOriginal="1" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="[\p{Punct}&amp;&amp;[^\-_\?\*]]" replacement=" "/>
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory"
                    generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0"
                    catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"
                    splitOnNumerics="0" preserveOriginal="1" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

I changed the field definition to:

```
<dynamicField name="*_fct_c" type="text_default" omitNorms="false" stored="false" />
```

After that change I get different scores for all the documents that contain the search term in the changed field.

The field is not contained in the returned Solr document, which is what I expected (and intended).

But I do not understand the changed scores, since the field is still indexed (as it was before) and I would not have expected that whether the field is stored or not affects the score. Also the official documention does not seem to imply anything like that.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you deleted the index and started from a clean index both times? Otherwise, if you just reindexed, the number of deleted documents in the index will vary between the two (and they still affect the score until they're expunged (i.e. the index is optimized or an index merge happens).

Comment: The index has been build from scratch both times, so the number of deletes documents is zero.

Comment: I will try and find a minimal example which I can reproduce without using my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my application does some atomic updates on startup.
With this term in mind I found the following article [Solr Atomic Update - update documents with fields that are indexed but not stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41922389/solr-atomic-update-update-documents-with-fields-that-are-indexed-but-not-srore) (I think I did not find it before due to a typo in the title).

This answer explains why the stored field gets lost. Unfortunaly I cannot use docValues="true" since I am using the TextField type, and will have to look for another workaround.

EDIT: We chose to use a DocTransformer as a workaround so that the field in question remains stored, but can be removed from Solr documents via the transformer.